# Azure VM InternalDnsSuffix

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

When you create a VM in Azure and ssh to it and run 'hostname -f' you get a hostname in the format of "vmname.InternalDnsSuffix". Is there a programatic/scriptable way to get InternalDnsSuffix for a ResourceGroup/Subscription/Subnet? I know I can get it for a running VM, but where do I get it for a stopped VM? Is there some way that I can just get it once for a set of VMs instead of querying each VM independently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a programatic/scriptable way to get InternalDnsSuffix for a
>   ResourceGroup/Subscription/Subnet?

That attribute only associate to Azure VM, so you should get this information from that VM.

You can use Azure REST API to run `hostname -f` command to get internal DNS suffix from a running VM:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}/runCommand?api-version=2017-03-30
```

More information about run command via REST API, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual%20machines%20run%20commands/runcommand).

Based on my knowledge, we **can't** get the dns suffix from a stopped VM or get internal dns suffix once for a set.